# How to use the query builder of Symfony to make a date range counter and fill the gaps with zeros

Tags: doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I have a query that count the user by grouping them by sign up date.

```php
return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
->select(' date(s.created_at) as x, count(1) as y')
->where("s.created_at between datesub(now(), :months, 'Month') and now()")
->setParameter('months', $months)
->groupBy('x')
->orderBy('x')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

But their is currently gaps in my dataset.

So I have the sql request to fill the gaps, but I don't know how to create a complicated request with the Symfony's query builder.

```sql
SELECT ranger.ranger_date AS x, COALESCE(counter.counter_value, 0) as y
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(s.created_at) AS counter_date, count(*) AS counter_value
    FROM statistic AS s
    WHERE s.created_at between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and now()
    GROUP BY counter_date
) AS counter
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 DAY)) AS ranger_date
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)hundreds
    WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 DAY) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW()
) AS ranger
ON ranger.ranger_date = counter.counter_date
ORDER BY ranger.ranger_date
```

I have already tried with the `createQuery` method, but it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your complex native sql query is successfully returning the result set you want:

You can simply [prepare and execute the query as documented by Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-sql).
If you need to hydrate entities then you can use [the NativeQuery class](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).